# svnadmin - migrating subdirectory of a project to the root directory of anther project

Tags: svn, migration, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

This is what I am trying to accomplish

```
Project_A
    -SubFolder_Y
         Project_X

Project_B
    Project_X
```

So basically migrating the subdirectory 'Project_X' from Project A to the root of Project B with all the revisions.

I am trying to use svnadmin commands since I have access to the SVN server.

I know I wanted to so something along the line of:

```
1. svnadmin dump \\Repositories\Project_A > ProjectA.dump
2. svndumpfilter include Project_X --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < Project_A.dump > Project_X.dump 
3. svnadmin load --ignore-uuid \\Repositories\Project_B <Project_X.dump
```

This doesn't seem to work, what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: ProjectA and ProjectB are different repositories, right?

Comment: *This doesn't seem to work, what am I missing here?* -- what exactly does not work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @bahrep Yes ProjectA and ProjectB are different. The above code would also keep 'SubFolder_Y' as the parent of Project_X which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you have to read [SVNBook chapter about repository history filtering](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering). And don't `svnadmin load` the dump to real repository before you test it with some test repo. You must ensure that the filtered dump that `svndumpfilter` generates contains all the data you expect and want it contain.

> The above code would also keep 'SubFolder_Y' as the parent of
>   Project_X which I do not want

This is covered in the doc chapter linked above. SVNBook suggests that you edit your dump files manually with a text editor or via script rewriting or removing the parent path (SubFolder__Y in your case). Complexity of this task depends on the number of revisions in your dump file, its size, repository paths etc. But in general, this is a non-trivial and potentially dangerous task and I'd recommend that you avoid modifying dump files manually.

Instead of rewriting parent paths, you could move Project_X to the root of the new repository after loading the filtered dump.

The command should be as follows:

[`svn move FROM-URL TO-URL -m "ENTER LOG MESSAGE"`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html)